# Browser Videos Crash Gnome

Tags: gnome, firefox, video

For the last few weeks I've had a problem in which the entire Gnome session will crash right back to the login prompt if a video tries to play in a browser.

I've not done an extensive test, because it's painful, but the problem definitely affects YouTube and Facebook videos in Firefox and Vivaldi. Twitch works absolutely fine.

Browsers installed using Flatpak are absolutely fine.

I have Ubuntu 19.04 with the latest updates, and I run Gnome. Both X11 and Wayland fail similarly. Probably some update is misbehaving, but nothing in the apt log looks obviously to blame.

Any suggestions how to fix it, please?

Comment: Twitch works absolutely fine.

Comment: I included your comment in the question. Please add any further pertinent information by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1176849/edit) the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem went away with the update to Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Do you have more information? I've the same issue in Fedora, but I don't understand the underlying issue, and it's not corrected in the last version

Comment: Sorry, no I never got to the bottom of it. :-(